# Organizing a List in Alphabetical order and using the append method

Tags: java, list, netbeans, collections, append

```
List <String> cdList = new ArrayList();
Collections.addAll(cdList, "ExampleG","ExampleB","ExampleR","ExampleX");

    bigBox.append("Original Order\n**************\n");

    for (String s : cdList)  {
    bigBox.append(s);
    bigBox.append("\n");
    }

    bigBox.append("\n\nSorted Order\n************\n");

    for (String s : cdList)  {
    bigBox.append(s);
    bigBox.append("\n");
    }
```

I need to organize the List in alphabetical order, and have it display below "Sorted order", but also need to keep the Original order for use under the original order line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original list:

```
// leave this variable untouched
List<String> cdList = Arrays.asList("ExampleG","ExampleB","ExampleR","ExampleX");
```

Sorted list:

```
List<String> sorted = new ArrayList<String>(cdList);
Collections.sort(sorted);  // "sorted" is the sorted list
```

Now you can iterate over `cdList` and `sorted`, and append them to `bigBox`:

```
bigBox.append("Original Order\n**************\n");
for (String s : cdList) {
    bigBox.append(s);
    bigBox.append("\n");
}
bigBox.append("\n\nSorted Order\n************\n");
for (String s : sorted) {
    bigBox.append(s);
    bigBox.append("\n");
}
```

There you go.

Answer (score 0):

You can't keep (and there is no point to) the different orders in the same list.

```
List <String> cdList = new ArrayList<String>();
Collections.addAll(cdList, "ExampleG","ExampleB","ExampleR","ExampleX");


List<String> sortedList = new ArrayList<String>(cdList);
Collections.sort(sortedList);
```

I strongly advise you to use generics if applicable.